# Is 0.0 the same as 0.000 in Rust?

Tags: rust, floating-point

I was aware of that the floating point is not precise, and from an question here on StackOverflow about rounding problem i learnt, to my understanding, that how precise it will be (until the hard limit, being around 15 digits after the decimal point) is depends on how many digits there are from the input.

This raise me a question, which I couldn’t find anywhere (or didn’t search for the right keywords?):
If what I conclude above is right, does that means calculation with `3.14` is less precies than `3.140`? and if so, are these number presented differently as `f64` in rust? What about zero (`0`, `0.0`, `0.00`)?

EDIT:
The reason I asked zero is that if after floating point calculation the result is zero or rounded to zero, is the precision preserved? (Say the input has two digits after point, is the result that’s zero presented as `0.0` or `0.00`?)

Comment: You know you can just [plug in those values and find out for yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8fc343642e374aeed8c54414a2ac7c7)

Comment: @cafce25 yeah, but I haven’t come to a calc that’s not precies as I expected

Comment: `3.14` is a decimal representation of a real number.`3.140` is another decimal representation of the *exact same* number. It matters not which one you type. Computers however generally operate with binary representations of real numbers. There is no exact finite binary representation of `3.14`, so the computer will use the closest one it can fit in a given number of bits (64 for `f64`).  `0.0` is a decimal representation of the number zero (so are `0.00` and `0.00000000`). Zero does have an exact binary representation that fits in 64 bits (or 32 bits, or 16 bits) so the computer will use it.

Comment: For example, `3.14f32` is actually `3.1400001049041748046875` (same as `3.140`) but `3.14f64` is `3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a993df25e9bcd26b2a06b5b159245f5)

Comment: Incidentally there are IEEE-754 explorers you can use to better understand the wonderful world of floats e.g. [floating point converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), [floating point explorer](https://kayru.org/articles/float/), [float exposed](https://float.exposed/).

Comment: And of course [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

> … i learnt, to my understanding, that how precise it will be (until the hard limit, being around 15 digits after the decimal point) is depends on how many digits there are from the input.

There is no such “hard limit,” and the floating-point number resulting from input does not depend on how many digits there are (given that digits in question are trailing zeros).

[Rust’s f64 format is IEEE-754 binary64.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html) The precision of this format is fixed at 53 binary digits and has nothing to do with how many digits there are in the input.

Each number that is representable in binary64 has only one representation, except for zero there is a +0 and a −0. Input of either “0.0” or “0.000” results in the +0 representation.